# Toast message in mobile testing - SeeTest

Tags: android, selenium, seetest

I am automating on Mobile using SeeTest Automation Tool, and I need to validate the Toast Message. How to do it? I am using Selenium WebDriver and C#.

Comment: Is it possible for you to "learn" the toast-object and wait for it to pop-up (ISElementFound)?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the toast element using SeeTest Studio. Add the inspected toast message as ToastMessage in Object repository. Use below code to verify toast message:

```
            Assert.IsTrue(
            client.WaitForElement(Zone, ToastMessage, 0, 30000),
            "ToastMessage is not displayed"
        );
```

Tis will wait for 30 seconds for the toast message to appear. If not the test will fail.

You can also make use of client.isElementFound method also. But since a toast message will appear for few seconds and disappear, WaitForElement is more suitable for this.